# How to integrate custom question answering (FAQ) bot into an existing azure bot in composer

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service, language-studio

I have made a chatbot that performs different actions using bot composer. Its showing an error while integrating a custom QNA bot into my existing project in composer .

[image: 1]

I was able to integrate the Custom QNA bot as new project in composer ,but unable to integrate it into my current project

Answer (score 0):

There is a Custom Question Answering Recognizer package that you can install in your Composer bot project that gives the ability to use the Azure Custom Question Answering Cognitive service in your bot.

Package:
https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-components/tree/main/packages/Recognizers/CustomQuestionAnswering/dotnet